# Google Chrome pre-pends % sign in front of search query in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, google-search

I have an issue where Google Chrome pre-pends a symbol to my search query when I open a new chrome tab and type a search query in the url bar.

For example. I open a new tab and type in "news" and the query returns with this "%news". Then I have to manually delete the % sign and search again for the keyword. Also, if I type in "d3" it automatically converts that into a "?" symbol and searches google for "?". This issue only happens when I open a new tab and search in the address bar. If I actually go to google.com it does not happen.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Chrome settings.
2. Under **Search**, you should find **Manage search engines...**.Click it.
3. Under **Default search engines**, you may find a name followed by **(Default)**.
4. In that row, go to the third column and look for **q=%%s**.
5. Edit that phrase into **q=%s**. (Remove the percentage mark)
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done.